# Console application hits break mode immediate

Tags: c#, visual-studio, console-application, breakpoints

I just downloaded a console app in c#. Trying to debug ends in the 'break mode screen'. Visual studio says: "Your app has entered a break state, but no code is currently executing that is supported by the selected debug engine (e.g. only native runtime code is executing)."

The application is an example to setup connection to a PLC.

```
using System;
using ControlLogixNET;
using ControlLogixNET.LogixType;

namespace ArrayTags
{
    class Program
    {
        /*
         * HOW TO USE THIS SAMPLE 
         * 
         * 1. First change the hostNameOrIp to the IP address or host name of your PLC
         * 2. Then change the path to be the path to your PLC, see comments below
         * 3. Create a 1 dimensional DINT array on the processor called dintArray1[10]
         * 4. Create a 2 dimensional DINT array on the processor called dintArray2[10,10]
         * 5. Create a 3 dimensional DINT array on the processor called dintArray3[10,10,10]
         * 6. Run
         * 
        */

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //First we create the processor object. Typically the path is the slot
            //number of the processor module in the backplane, but if your communications
            //card is not in the same chassis as your processor, this is the path through
            //the chassis to get to your processor. You will have to add a 1 for every
            //chassis you go through, for example:
            //Chassis 1: ENBT card in Slot 1 (slot is irrelavent), ControlNet Card in Slot 2
            //Chassis 2: L61 in Slot 4
            //Path would be: { 2, 1, 4 }
            //Basically it's the target slot, 1 for backplane, target slot, 1 for backplane...
            //until you get to the processor.
            string hostNameOrIp = "169.254.125.220";
            byte[] path = new byte[] { 3 };
            LogixProcessor processor = new LogixProcessor(hostNameOrIp, path);

            //The processor has to be connected before you add any tags or tag groups.
            if (!processor.Connect())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Could not connect to the processor");
                Console.ReadKey(false);
                return;
            }

            //First create a group. Groups are much more efficient at reading and writing
            //large numbers of tags.
            LogixTagGroup myGroup = processor.CreateTagGroup("MyGroup");

            //Now let's create our first array. The number of elements is the TOTAL number
            //of elements to read, in all dimensions. 
            LogixDINT dintArray1 = new LogixDINT("dintArray1", processor, 10);

            //We don't need to set the number of dimensions on the tag here because it
            //assumes that it's a single dimension tag. All tags are set up to be arrays
            //by default, the .Value or similar member always returns the 0th element
            //of the array. With a tag that is not an array, that is where the value is.

            //Let's create the 2 dimensional array
            LogixDINT dintArray2 = new LogixDINT("dintArray2", processor, 100);

            //The number of elements are the subscripts multiplied by each other. In this
            //case, 10*10 = 100. If you put a lower value here you will only read that
            //much of the array. ControlLogix packs it's arrays in row major format, so
            //just keep that in mind if reading partial arrays.

            //If you want to set it up to read with a multidimensional accessor, we need
            //to tell the tag what the size of the dimensions are.
            dintArray2.SetMultipleDimensions(10, 10);

            //We can now access the tag by the tagName[row,column] format. If you didn't
            //set the size, you would get an exception when trying to access the tag
            //using that format.

            //Let's create the last tag
            LogixDINT dintArray3 = new LogixDINT("dintArray3", processor, 1000);

            //Set the dimensions
            dintArray3.SetMultipleDimensions(10, 10, 10);

            //Now let's add our tags to the tag group...
            myGroup.AddTag(dintArray1);
            myGroup.AddTag(dintArray2);
            myGroup.AddTag(dintArray3);

            Console.WriteLine("6D Systems LLC\n\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Tags created...");

            //Now let's pick out some random members and display them...
            Console.WriteLine("dintArray1[4]     = " + dintArray1[4].ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("dintArray2[5,2]   = " + dintArray2[5, 2].ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("dintArray3[4,7,3] = " + dintArray3[4, 7, 3].ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("\nPress any key to write a new value to each of the above tags");
            Console.ReadKey(false);

            //Now let's write some data to those tags...
            Random rnd = new Random();
            dintArray1[4] = rnd.Next(int.MinValue, int.MaxValue);
            dintArray2[5, 2] = rnd.Next(int.MinValue, int.MaxValue);
            dintArray3[4, 7, 3] = rnd.Next(int.MinValue, int.MaxValue);

            //Let's update the tag group
            processor.UpdateGroups();

            //Now print them back out for the user...
            Console.WriteLine("\nNew tag values...");
            Console.WriteLine("dintArray1[4]     = " + dintArray1[4].ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("dintArray2[5,2]   = " + dintArray2[5, 2].ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("dintArray3[4,7,3] = " + dintArray3[4, 7, 3].ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("\nPress any key to quit");
            Console.ReadKey(false);

            //Remember to disconnect from the processor
            processor.Disconnect();

        }
    }
}
```

Only special in this project is the custom made library that handle the TCP/IP connection to the PLC. These library's are downloadable [here](https://controllogixnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#trunk/Examples/ArrayTags/Program.cs).

Also good to know is the value of the output windows, it says:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in Unknown Module.
> Could not load file or assembly 'ControlLogixNET, Version=1.1.4597.20464, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

---

UPDATE:

I throw the ControlLogixNET.dll file into "Dependency Walker" gives my this result:

> Error: Modules with different CPU types were found. Warning: At least
> one delay-load dependency module was not found. Warning: At least one
> module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in a
> delay-load dependent module."

Could this be a problem?

Comment: An error has occured in referenced code that you do not have and is likely non-managed code.

Comment: I strongly recommend the Snap7 project C# class for PLC communication (Siemens), totally debbugable.

Comment: This test project is for an application running with Rockwell PLC's (Allen Bradley)

Comment: It seems as if you need another version of the ControlLogixNET library. Which CPU type does your project use?

Comment: Do you know your solution platform, and that of the third party library?  It looks to me like your project could have AnyCPU configuration, and the library is a specific Debug/Release configuration.

Comment: I tried to run in different CPU configurations, but that keeps me with the same error all the time. I have no clue what the recommended CPU-type is, but after trying all types nothing works, so I still thinks the problem is somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Do you also have the EIPNET code or dll in which ControlLogixNET depends on?

Comment: Nope, I figured out that this library wasn't compatible with my UWP-application. In the meantime I wrote a library for UWP by myself to get my project working.